# Inheritance UIViewController in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have `FirstViewController`(parent) an I have created it in storyboard, it integrating camera(`AVCaptureSession`) and containing (`UILabel`, `UIButton`s, `UIView`, `UIImage`), I have created `SecondViewController` which inherits `FirstViewController` to avoid duplicate the `FirstViewController` and I am changing label in the `SecondViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"### viewDidLoad ###");
    text = @"Je me prends en photo";
    [self setTextField:text];
    [CaptureSession initializeCamera];
}
```

to modify label

```
-(void) setTextField : (NSString*) text{
self.textFieldDisplay.text = text;
}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [CaptureSession initializeCamera];
   textDisplay = @"Prends un selfie et défie tes amis !";
   [super setTextField:textDisplay];   
}
```

My problème is I can't display label in the `SecondViewController` !
if you have document concerning inheritance `UIViewController` I'll take it.

Comment: Why are you inheriting the Secondviewcontroller from Fierstviewcontroller?

Comment: As Munahil asked, why are you making `SecondViewController` inherit from `FirstViewController`? Is the only difference the string that you're using in the text field? If so... you could just have one class and pass in the string on creation, or set it in a property...

Comment: to avoid duplication of ViewController, i'll use the same content of FierstViewController 5 times

Comment: From what you've written, it seems like there is some common functionality, e.g. the `CaptureSession`, and some things that are different, e.g. `text = @"Je me prends en photo";` and `textDisplay = @"Prends un selfie et défie tes amis !";`... could you say more about what is different between the view controllers you want to use?

Comment: when you initialize the first controller, xcode takes the storyboard instance and loads the views from there since you have a controller with that name defined. When you initialize the second one, xcode doesn't find any instance in the storyboard with that name so it doesn't load the views for that controller, instead uses regular alloc/init. You have to create a controller instance in the storyboard for the second one, add the label and views etc, and connect them to the first view controller IBOutlets in Fierstviewcontroller.h

Comment: look the FirstViewController i use it in inscription i taking photo with camera or choose it in library and the result i saving image. then i need to use this viewcontroller to save others images .

Comment: Here is another suggestion, don't create another view controller, make changes in the same ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I don't use inheritance just I created `static string` in `SecondViewController`

eg: `static nsstring *test = @"test"`, and save it in delegate when I'm going in `FirstViewController` I test it in method and I change label in `FirstViewController` like I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIViewControllerGeneric with all the common properties, and then inherit both viewcontrollers from it, I think it's the correct way

Comment: Can i use FirstViewController many times ? and i'll change it every use.

Comment: You have to use a concrete viewcontroller in each case, try what I said, i think is waht you want

Comment: I did not understand your solution VictorG !!

Comment: Create a new uiviewcontroller class, let's say "MyViewController", put in it everything that will be common for the other two viewcontrollers and then create the first and second viewcontroller: and inherit both from myViewcontroller instead of uiviewcontroller, did you got me?